# Error on displaying the forum data

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have tried to show the output of the data from database but it shows error. I want to create forum that will show the message on a same page

My error is at:

$mysqli_query($sql);

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_query

Fatal error: Function name must be a string

My coding is

`
        if(trim($_POST['forum_numberUser']) == NULL || trim($_POST['forum_text']) == NULL )

```
       { // If the user didn't fill in all fields
        echo "<h3>PLEASE COMPLETE THE FORM TO REGISTER</h3>";
    }
    else {
        include('connect.php');

        $_SESSION['FILLED'] = TRUE;
        // username and password sent from form 
        $mynumberUser=$_POST['forum_numberUser']; 
        $mytext=$_POST['forum_text'];
       // $mydate=$_POST['forum_date'];


        // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
        $mynumberUser = stripslashes($mynumberUser);
        $mytext = stripslashes($mytext);
        $mynumberUser = mysql_real_escape_string($mynumberUser);
        $mytext = mysql_real_escape_string($mytext);
        $mydate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //$mytime=date('H:i:s');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO forum VALUES(null, '$mynumberUser', '$mytext', '$mydate')";
       $mysqli_query($sql); //HERE IS MY ERROR...


        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) === TRUE) {


             //&['forum_text']
            echo "Successfully registered ";
        }
        else {
            echo "<h4>Unable to register.</h4>";
        } 
    }

}`
```

Comment: remove the dollar before mysqli_query

Comment: I don't think you did enough research before asking this question..

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$` before the function call `mysqli_query()`, which is the syntax for variables, not functions.

Comment: i have removed it . and shows  Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters

Comment: Lo and behold, it sure does: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php RTFM